# Making a table from CI output

Tags: r, datatable, output

I am trying to make a table from my CI output, I do not have experience making tables in R and would really appreciate some help.

```
CI <- data %>% group_by(group) %>% summarize(CI_z(column1, ci = 0.95))
```

I am using CI_z function to get my confidence interval information. I have 4 groups in that my data is being grouped into. My output looks like this:

```
group     Measurements   values
   <chr>     <chr>           <dbl>
 1 group1  sample_size     11   
 2 group1  Mean            39.3 
 3 group1  sd               6.35
 4 group1  Margin_Error     3.75
 5 group1  CI.lower.limit  35.5 
 6 group1  CI.Upper.limit  43.0 
 7 group2 sample_size      8   
 8 group2 Mean            35.2 
 9 group2 sd               4.79
10 group2 Margin_Error     3.32
```

etc. until group4 is finished

I want to extract the data from this output that makes a table in the following format:

| Group | N | Mean | Lower Limit | Upper limit |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Group1 | x | x | x | x |
| Group2 | x | x | x | x |
| Group3 | x | x | x | x |
| Group4 | x | x | x | x |

I know how to use:
`CI[,]` 
to get specific data from a column and row, but I do not know how to use this to make a the table that I want. Any advise on how to go about this would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Please share your data using `dput`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a possible `data.table` option (thanks to @langtang for the data):

```
library(data.table)

dt <- as.data.table(df)

results <- setnames(dt[,dcast(dt, group ~ Measurements, value.var = "values")][, !c("sd", "Margin_Error"), with=FALSE],
         c("Group", "Upper Limit", "Lower Limit", "Mean", "N"))
```

**Output**

```
    Group Upper Limit Lower Limit Mean  N
1: group1        43.0        35.5 39.3 11
2: group2        47.1        25.8 35.2  8
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do the following, which uses `dplyr` and `tidyr`, and assumes data is `df`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>% 
  filter(!Measurements %in% c("sd", "Margin_Error")) %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from=Measurements, values_from=values) %>% 
  rename_with(~c("Group", "N", "Mean", "Lower Limit", "Upper Limit"))
```

Output:

```
  Group      N  Mean `Lower Limit` `Upper Limit`
  <chr>  <dbl> <dbl>         <dbl>         <dbl>
1 group1    11  39.3          35.5          43  
2 group2     8  35.2          25.8          47.1
```

Input:

```
df = structure(list(group = c("group1", "group1", "group1", "group1", 
"group1", "group1", "group2", "group2", "group2", "group2", "group2", 
"group2"), Measurements = c("sample_size", "Mean", "sd", "Margin_Error", 
"CI.lower.limit", "CI.Upper.limit", "sample_size", "Mean", "sd", 
"Margin_Error", "CI.lower.limit", "CI.Upper.limit"), values = c(11, 
39.3, 6.35, 3.75, 35.5, 43, 8, 35.2, 4.79, 3.32, 25.8, 47.1)), row.names = c(NA, 
-12L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: thank you, this exactly what I needed. It worked perfectly.